# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, import

`The declared package "" does not match the expected package "src"`
I am trying to compile this program and I get the above error. 
I imported the project from the downloads folder and copied it to my workspace. Do i need to create a new package ? 
[image: screenshot]

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Yes. you need to create then put them in their right packages.

Comment: How have you imported the project to workspace?

Comment: yes I did , how do I add them in the right package ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you have done.. But it looks like you havent imported it into the workspace correctly.

If this is a project you have downloaded , just use import-> existing projects into workspace.

Comment: Ok then create a package with the required name and then move all those classes into that. I am surprised a working downloaded project wasnt already in the right package

Comment: so i created a new package src1 and moved it there
compiling the program gives me thiss error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at src1.STS.main(STS.java:23)

Answer (score 0):

There is a

> default package

under the src and if you put classes under that it will works fine. The other solution is to create a project manually and add one class and copy paste individually which is not so pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

I thik you will have to configure your source location for the project. Do the following thing stated in the image below. Click on "Add Folder" and the location of the source folder

[image]

Comment: The you will have to configure libraries for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is happened because your class is not in correct package, you should put your class under defaults package then your issue will be fine; otherwise you should write in top of your class ,your package name for example " mohsen package;"

Answer (score -2):

make sure your 'S' is capital in System.out.println();

Answer (score -2):

You would have removed the package name in any of the class by mistake. Inspect all the classes for correct package name.